# In Before Flow: How to set a Text field from standard Email field on a related contact record?

Tags: email, visual-workflow, fields

I've attempted both options:

1. creating a text variable, assigning the email field's value to it, and then updating the text field with the text variable; and
2. updating the text field directly with the email field.

In both cases, the Flow does not recognize the value of the email field, even though it's not blank on the related record. Please note that updates work correctly with other field types like Email to Email and Text to Text, but not Text to Email.

[image]

Comment: To help us help you, it would be useful if you could include some more detail in your question. How are the record's related for example and including a screenshot of the assignment/record update nodes would be great. The screenshot you have doesn't seem related to your question. Could you please [edit] your question to add more details.